# How can I create a visual customizable settings in admin panel of my website?

Tags: php, css

I want to create a visual customizable settings in admin panel of my site, this means that when user change some settings, see the results live on the page. Is there any open source PHP script for this purpose?

I don't have any idea how can I do that.

Maybe this question is too general and should be more specific but any help would be useful for me.

[Edit]
I want to create something like this web site (but very very smaller than it) :

http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com/

which technologies I should use?

Comment: So, you're looking at the Bootstrap theme roller website and asking about an open source technology that does what that does? How about **Bootstrap** y'know, since that's what you're looking at anyway?!

Comment: I want to create a page that has a textbox for value and an image at the same page and when i change the value in the textbox i see the results on the page. For example changing image width. It's not related to bootstrap, that was just an example. @CD001

Comment: A 10 second search turned this up : http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/ but that's not really what SO is about; try something and when you get stuck, ask a question for technical help on that specific problem...